# Wrong RowTotal price when custom modules are active

Tags: price, tax, totals

My RowTotal - excluding tax price takes wrong value when my custom modules (for add row with custom item to Rowtotal) are active - It takes value/price with inlcluding tax.

But just when both of my two custom modules ( one for each custom row in rowtotals ) are active.

If just one is active ( no matter which one ) it works fine and rowtotal-excluding tax takes correct value.

Please advice in which file of my modules can be problem so I can paste code here.

Comment: Do you rewrite the same models or blocks in both extensions?

Comment: yes it seems that was the problem. Thanks for advice.